# Getting the error in JSON parsing in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I am trying to pars the json data and display in table 
My JSON data is like this

```
{"isError":false,"ErrorMessage":"","Result":{"Count":4,"Data":[{"ContentID":"127_30_1309793318065","ContentTypeID":1,"UserCaption":"Gandhinagar(Kanjurmarg)","UserComment":"central\n","DateRecorded":"\/Date(1309793318000+0530)\/","Data":"","ShareType":true,"Views":0,"PlayTime},{},{},{}];};isError = 0;}
```

I am prasing like this

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{      
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);  



    //this is for the getting the data from the server with help of JSON
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];
    /
    //this for holding the Array value which come from the server 
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int index = 0; index<[reviewsvalues count]; index++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * value = [reviewsvalues objectAtIndex:index];
        ReviewsResult * result = [[ReviewsResult alloc] init];
        result.User_Caption = [value objectForKey:@"UserCaption"];
        result.ContentType_Id = [value objectForKey:@"DateRecorded"];
        result.Average_Rating = [value objectForKey:@"AverageRating"];
        //OVER here MY APP GET CRASH 


    }


}
```

BUt it get crash and give error

**[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple.

`reviewsvalues` should be an NSDictionary and you should not be calling `objectAtIndex:` for the `reviewsvalues`.

Instead you should call `valueForKey` like

```
int count = [[reviewsvalues valueForKey:@"Count"] intValue];
NSArray *reviewsArray = [reviewsvalues valueForKey:@"Data"];
int count = [reviewsArray count];

cell.textLabel.text = [[reviewsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ContentID"];
```

Hope this helps you.

Please let me know if you want more help on this.

Comment: Yes you are right but done like this NSArray *reviewsArray = [reviewsvalues valueForKey:@"Data"]; but ? how can i set the value on to the cell and how can count row

Comment: @Harish: reviewArray at each of its index contains a dictionary.

Comment: Can you come on line chat on stackchat

Comment: @Harish: I have edited my answer and given more code on how you need to do this. Hope this helps. If you still have doubts then please let me know

Comment: @Harish: Can you please wait for half an hour for participating in stackchat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4016/discussion-between-harish-and-parth-bhatt)

Comment: are you there value is not getting display on cell

Comment: Does it come in NSLog if you print it in console

Answer (score 1):

You set `reviewsvalues = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];`

Which means `reviewsvalues` is now an `NSDictionary`.
"Result" is a dictionary, not an array:

```
{"Count":4,"Data":[...]}
```

`NSDictionary` doesn't respond to `-objectAtIndex:`, that's one of `NSArray`'s methods.

You need another step:

```
NSArray *reviewsArray = [reviewsvalues objectForKey:@"Data"];
```

and while you are at it, you can use fast enumeration.

```
for (NSDictionary *review in reviewsArray) {
    ReviewsResult * result = [[ReviewsResult alloc] init];
    result.User_Caption = [review objectForKey:@"UserCaption"];
    result.ContentType_Id = [review objectForKey:@"DateRecorded"];
    result.Average_Rating = [review objectForKey:@"AverageRating"];
}
```

Edit: also, you should know that you've not coded this very defensively. What happens if the data isn't exactly as it is in your example? what happens if a value is missing, like "Data", or "Result"?
Your app should be robust enough to not choke if something slightly unexpected happens.

Comment: Than how can i handle when something slightly unexpected happens.

Comment: even it not work it get crash and give error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]:

Comment: at this link NSArray *reviewsArray = [reviewsvalues objectAtIndex:@"Data"]; it show me warning that passing argument 1 of 'objectAtIndex'makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: @harish Sorry, my mistake, should be `objectForKey:` not `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: @harish have a look at the headers for NSDictionary, and NSArray... try to keep them separate in your mind. Be aware that you will mix them up (as I just did). That's what compiler warnings are for ;)